# FindFirstFile matches wildcards that shouldn't match

Tags: delphi, winapi, cmd, wildcard

On some of my Windows 10 machines, `FindFirstFile` matches files that definitely should not match. Assume the following program in Delphi:

```
{$apptype console}
uses Windows;

var
  FindHandle: THandle;
  FindData: WIN32_FIND_DATA;

begin
  FindHandle := FindFirstFile('*.qqq', FindData);
  if FindHandle <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then
  begin
    try
      repeat
        Writeln(PChar(@FindData.cFileName[0]));
      until not FindNextFile(FindHandle, FindData);
    finally
      FindClose(FindHandle);
    end;
  end;
end.
```

and four files:

```
a.qqq
b.qqqt
c.qqqx
c.qqq123
```

The output I expect to get is just `a.qqq`. But what actually happens is, all four files get printed out. I get the same result with CMD's `dir *.qqq`, too, so it's not just Delphi doing weird stuff, but PowerShell's `dir *.qqq` works as expected. What could possibly be causing this behavior? And particularly, if it is some specific settings in the OS (which seems to be indicated by the fact that I don't get this result on **all** machines, just **some**), is there something I can do from within my program to enforce the expected behavior regardless of the OS settings?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason is that the underlying Windows functions checks the long and the short file names:

> The search includes the long and short file names.

You can see that when you add the /X parameter to the dir call in CMD:

```
dir /X *.qqq
```

A possible solution is to add another filter check for each found name that only takes the long name.

Actually, that is what Delphi does in `TDirectory.GetFiles`, making that sometimes a better alternative to the hand written routine.